# Getting a return for unique date and stock name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'd like to get a percent return for a set of close stock prices whereby the returns are for each pair of date and ticker symbol.

An example of the dataframe:

```
       date      open  high    low     close    volume Name

0   2013-02-08  15.07   15.12   14.63   14.75   8407500 AAL
1   2013-02-11  14.89   15.01   14.26   14.46   8882000 AAL
2   2013-02-12  14.45   14.51   14.10   14.27   8126000 AAL
3   2013-02-13  14.30   14.94   14.25   14.66   10259500    AAL
4   2013-02-14  14.94   14.96   13.16   13.99   31879900    AAL
```

I can easily get the change via df.close.pct_change(1) for the column, but it needs to be grouped.

Things I've tried:

1.GroupBy and apply: `df.groupby(by=['date', 'Name']).apply(lambda x: x.assign(ret= d['close'].pct_change(1)))`

However, this produces all NaN values.

```
                       date      open   high    low close   volume  Name    ret
date    Name                                    
2013-02-08  AAL 0   2013-02-08  15.07   15.12   14.63   14.75   8407500 AAL NaN
2013-02-11  AAL 1   2013-02-11  14.89   15.01   14.26   14.46   8882000 AAL NaN
2013-02-12  AAL 2   2013-02-12  14.45   14.51   14.10   14.27   8126000 AAL NaN
2013-02-13  AAL 3   2013-02-13  14.30   14.94   14.25   14.66   10259500    AAL NaN
2013-02-14  AAL 4   2013-02-14  14.94   14.96   13.16   13.99   31879900    AAL NaN
```

2. GroupBy close: `df['ret'] = df.groupby(by=['date', 'Name']).close`

Which produces.

```
    date        open    high    low     close   volume  Name    ret
0   2013-02-08  15.07   15.12   14.63   14.75   8407500 AAL ((2013-02-08, AAL), [14.75])
1   2013-02-11  14.89   15.01   14.26   14.46   8882000 AAL ((2013-02-11, AAL), [14.46])
2   2013-02-12  14.45   14.51   14.10   14.27   8126000 AAL ((2013-02-12, AAL), [14.27])
3   2013-02-13  14.30   14.94   14.25   14.66   10259500    AAL ((2013-02-13, AAL), [14.66])
4   2013-02-14  14.94   14.96   13.16   13.99   31879900    AAL ((2013-02-14, AAL), [13.99])
```

I believe the data I need is in the returned group object, but after trying some index slicing I haven't been able to extract the data.

Can I please have some assistance? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To compute percent change for each group in `Name`:

```
df.groupby('Name')['close'].pct_change()
```

Runnable example with a second name added for demo purposes:

```
d = {'Name': ['AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'AAL', 'TST', 'TST', 'TST'],
     'close': [14.75, 14.46, 14.27, 14.66, 13.99, 10, 11, 22],
     'date': [Timestamp('2013-02-08 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2013-02-11 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2013-02-12 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2013-02-13 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2013-02-14 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2013-02-11 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2013-02-12 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2013-02-13 00:00:00')],
     'high': [15.12, 15.01, 14.51, 14.94, 14.96, 11, 12, 23],
     'low': [14.63, 14.26, 14.1, 14.25, 13.16, 9, 10, 21],
     'open': [15.07, 14.89, 14.45, 14.3, 14.94, 10, 11, 22],
     'volume': [8407500,
                8882000,
                8126000,
                10259500,
                31879900,
                8126000,
                10259500,
                31879900]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['ret'] = df.groupby('Name')['close'].pct_change()

print(df)

        date   open   high    low  close    volume Name       ret
0 2013-02-08  15.07  15.12  14.63  14.75   8407500  AAL       NaN
1 2013-02-11  14.89  15.01  14.26  14.46   8882000  AAL -0.019661
2 2013-02-12  14.45  14.51  14.10  14.27   8126000  AAL -0.013140
3 2013-02-13  14.30  14.94  14.25  14.66  10259500  AAL  0.027330
4 2013-02-14  14.94  14.96  13.16  13.99  31879900  AAL -0.045703
5 2013-02-11  10.00  11.00   9.00  10.00   8126000  TST       NaN
6 2013-02-12  11.00  12.00  10.00  11.00  10259500  TST  0.100000
7 2013-02-13  22.00  23.00  21.00  22.00  31879900  TST  1.000000
```